# How to set the value of a cell depending of 2 other criteria

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, excel-formula

I have an Excel tab like this.

It give me information on when a worker is plan to start on a product.

The Columns of my input Table are:

```
Product Number, Dummy column, Dummy column, Worker ID, Starting Date, Ending Date
```

The lines in my input Table are:

```
Product 1,xyz,xyz,Worker 1,13/08/2018 13:50,20/08/2018 15:30
Product 1,xyz,xyz,Worker 2,08/08/2018 03:50,16/08/2018 08:30
Product 1,xyz,xyz,Worker 9,23/08/2018 08:08,03/09/2018 10:00
Product 2,xyz,xyz,Worker 4,10/08/2018 13:50,27/08/2018 15:30
Product 2,xyz,xyz,Worker 9,18/08/2018 03:50,20/08/2018 08:30
Product 3,xyz,xyz,Worker 2,13/08/2018 08:08,13/09/2018 10:00
```

My Result table should have:

- one line per Worker
- one Column for each day of the year

The values in the Result Tab should show for a given Worker and a Given Date on which Product the Worker started to work.
So the cell could be empty if at this date the workerX didn't start to work on a product.

Do you have an idea how I can solve this in Excel (or Access if not possible in Excel)?

Comment: Any table with a column for each day of the year is going to be unwieldy...is there any way you can simplify the data (maybe weeks or months instead of days)?

Answer (score 0):

Access is probably going to be your best bet. You will want to create a column that strips the time value from the **Starting Date** column, leaving you with only the day value. Let's call that the **Starting Day** for now. Now create a crosstab query based on your table. The rows will be based on the **Worker ID** column. The columns will be based on the **Starting Day** column.  The value will use the aggregate function called "First()" on the **Product Number** field.

I think it should look something like this in SQL (replace <YOURTABLE> with your table name):

```
TRANSFORM First([Product Number])
SELECT [Worker ID] FROM <YOURTABLE> GROUP BY [Worker ID]
PIVOT [Starting Day]
```

Good luck!

Comment: One side-note about this answer: It only reports days on which a worker started a product. As @Sam pointed out, having a table with 365 columns is a bit difficult to manage. If you absolutely must have 356 columns, you'll need to have an interim query that fills in the missing days or simply append the missing days as dummy rows to your table.

Comment: Note the [maximum number of fields in a table is 255](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c).  That also applies to a query recordset.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer your data in column A.

In cells C2 to C20, type the names of the workers Worker 1, Worker 2, etc, in the same way as it is present in the data.

In row 1, enter the dates, starting from cell D1.

In my example, cell D1 is 7 Aug 2018, E1 is 8 Aug 2018., …

In cell D2, enter the following **Array Formula**

**=IF(MAX(IFERROR(FIND($C2&","&TEXT(D$1,"dd/mm/yyyy"),$A$1:$A$1000,1),0))=0,"-","Yes")**

Array Formulas are entered using **Control + Shift + Enter**, instead of Enter.

Drag the formula to the required cells.
The result will be "Yes" if a worker has started a project on a particular date, and "-" if no project has been started by a worker on a particular date.

Change the cell references as required.

In place of "Yes", if you want to get the **Product details** as the result, then use the below **Array Formula** in cell D2.

**=IFERROR(LEFT(IF((MAX(IF(IFERROR(FIND($C2&","&TEXT(D$1,"dd/mm/yyyy"),$A$1:$A$1000,1),0)>0,ROW($1:$1000),"-")))=0,"-",INDEX($A$1:$A$1000,(MAX(IF(IFERROR(FIND($C2&","&TEXT(D$1,"dd/mm/yyyy"),$A$1:$A$1000,1),0)>0,ROW($1:$1000),"-"))),1)), FIND($C2,IF((MAX(IF(IFERROR(FIND($C2&","&TEXT(D$1,"dd/mm/yyyy"),$A$1:$A$1000,1),0)>0,ROW($1:$1000),"-")))=0,"-",INDEX($A$1:$A$1000,(MAX(IF(IFERROR(FIND($C2&","&TEXT(D$1,"dd/mm/yyyy"),$A$1:$A$1000,1),0)>0,ROW($1:$1000),"-"))),1)),1)-2),"-")**

Do let me know if this is what you wanted to do.

Regards,

Vijaykumar Shetye,

Spreadsheet Excellence,

Panaji, Goa, India